# NVelocity template error in c#

Tags: asp.net, apache, velocity, nvelocity, parse-error

I am fairly new in using NVelocity. I am trying to edit some of the old templates for my company and i ma getting this error which i dont understand. OK so in template, if order has multiple shipments then show multiple shipment name and if only one then show only one shipment name. when there is multiple shipments, it works fine BUT when there is only one then somehow template does not renders the required shiment name instead printout the class name.

```
 #if($order.Shipments.Count > 1) 
 #foreach($shipment in $order.Shipments)
 #beforeall 
 #each 
 $shipment.ShipMethodName <strong>|</strong> 
 #else
 $order.Shipments[0].ShipMethodName  // in emails it renders "Orders.OrderShipmentCollection[0].ShipMethodName"
 #end
 #end
```

Please help.

Comment: Sorry if stupid question, but your _else_ clause seems to just handle the 0 shipment case. Am I wrong ?

Comment: yes...thats right ....i have edited the question... it seems that its still not working...

Comment: I'm with @jbl, confused by your if statement that has "> 0" rather than "> 1". You've also edited an error into the template because it is now missing an #end statement for the foreach. 

If you aren't aware NVelocity will usually write out the template variable reference (e.g. "$order.Shipments[0].ShipMethodName") when something is null or fails, but it shouldn't write out the type names. I'd try printing out "$order.Shipments[0]" and debug the data being passed through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but in case someone is looking for a solution later I thought I'd post an answer as I was going through old questions that don't have accepted answers. I don't how I didn't notice the error when I posted that comment in September last year.

`$order.Shipments[0].ShipMethodName` is giving you `Orders.OrderShipmentCollection[0].ShipMethodName` because NVelocity doesn't support indexers like C#, you need to use the `get_Item()` method, i.e. `$order.Shipments.get_Item(0).ShipMethodName` that is the underlying method the C# compiler creates for indexers.

What is happening is `$order.Shipments` prints out the type name (`Orders.OrderShipmentCollection`) and the rest `[0].ShipMethodName` just gets printed verbatim.